# Why is the sum of the area under density curve always greater than 1 (R)?

Tags: r

I found codes to calculate the sum of the area under a density curve in R. Unfortunately, I don't understand why there is always an extra ~"0.000976" at the area...

```
nb.data = 500000
y = rnorm(nb.data,10,2)

de = density(y)

require(zoo)
sum(diff(de$x[order(de$x)])*rollmean(de$y[order(de$x)],2))

[1] 1.000976
```

Why is that so?

It should be equal to 1, right?

Comment: Rounding errors?

Comment: Would there be a way to correct for that?

Comment: Same as any other language, I guess. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759910/preventing-rounding-errors) to be particularly helpful, but I'm not sure how well it'd apply to your situation.

Comment: note that this is off by almost exactly  `1/(2*length(de$y))`

Comment: It must be related to the distribution and the integration algorithm. You alwas use normal distribution, I suppose? And implicitely the same integration algroritm.

Comment: I wish that I could upvote @BenBolker 's comment more than once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This discrepancy is not just due to rounding errors or floating-point arithmetic. You are effectively interpolating linearly between the points computed by `density` and then computing the area under this approximation to the original function (i.e. you are integrating the curve using the [trapzoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)), which means that you are overestimating the area in regions of the curve that are concave up and underestimating it in regions that are concave down. Here's an example image from the Wikipedia article demonstrating the systematic error:

---

[image: Trapezoidal rule illustration]

<sup>Image by Intégration_num_trapèzes.svg: Scalerderivative work: Cdang (talk) - Intégration_num_trapèzes.svg, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=8541370</sup>

---

Since the normal distribution has more concave up areas (i.e. both tails), the overall estimate is too high. As mentioned in another answer, using a higher resolution (i.e. increasing N) helps to minimize the error. You might also get better results using a different method for numerical integration (e.g. [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule)).

However, there is no numerical integration method that is going to give you an exact answer, and even if there was, the return value of `density` is only an approximation of the real distribution anyway. (And for real data, the true distribution is unknown.)

If all you want is the satisfaction of seeing a known density function integrating to 1, you can use `integrate` on the normal density function:

```
> integrate(dnorm, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, mean=10, sd=2)
1 with absolute error < 4.9e-06
```

Comment: Indeed, I thought it would be more challenging! It's even better with the integral.

Answer (score 10):

That's calculus. Use higher `n` (default is 512) for *more accurate* result

```
set.seed(42)
de = density(rnorm(500000, 10, 2))
sum(diff(sort(de$x)) * 0.5 * (de$y[-1] + head(de$y, -1)))
#[1] 1.00098

set.seed(42)
de = density(rnorm(500000, 10, 2), n = 1000)
sum(diff(sort(de$x)) * 0.5 * (de$y[-1] + head(de$y, -1)))
#[1] 1.000491

set.seed(42)
de = density(rnorm(500000, 10, 2), n = 10000)
sum(diff(sort(de$x)) * 0.5 * (de$y[-1] + head(de$y, -1)))
#[1] 1.000031

set.seed(42)
de = density(rnorm(500000, 10, 2), n = 100000)
sum(diff(sort(de$x)) * 0.5 * (de$y[-1] + head(de$y, -1)))
#[1] 1.000004

set.seed(42)
de = density(rnorm(500000, 10, 2), n = 1000000)
sum(diff(sort(de$x)) * 0.5 * (de$y[-1] + head(de$y, -1)))
#[1] 1
```