# Rounding error detection

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding-error

I have two integers n and d. These can be exactly represented by double dn(n) and double dd(d). Is there a reliable way in C++ to check if

```
double result = dn/dd
```

contains a rounding error? If it was just an integer-division checking if `(n/d) * d==n` would work but doing that with double precision arithmetic could  hide rounding errors.

Edit: Shortly after posting this it struck me that changing the rounding mode to round_down would make the `(n/d)*d==n` test work for double. But if there is a simpler solution, I'd still like to hear it.

Comment: @Ron that's the point. I can't represent 1/10 but I can represent 2/4. The goal is to check if it is possible.

Comment: Test if d is a power of 2. If not and n is no multiple of d, then n/d is **not** exactly representable as double.

Comment: @gammatester: 9/3 is exactly representable as integer and thus also as double.

Comment: Already edited.

Comment: I would recommend you to consider a must read on this topic. Check the Rounding Errors section in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. Also, you might the following useful:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759910/preventing-rounding-errors

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008395/rounding-problem-with-double-type

Comment: @gammatester `d` doesn't have to be either a power of two or a divisor of `n`, it can be the product of the two. Example: d=6, n=3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ignore overflow and underflow (which you should be able to do unless the integer types representing `d` and `n` are very wide), then the (binary) floating-point division `dn/dd` is exact iff `d` is a divisor of `n` times a power of two.

An algorithm to check for this may look like:

```
assert(d != 0);
while (d & 1 == 0) d >>= 1; // extract largest odd divisor of d
int exact = n % d == 0;
```

This is cheaper than changing the FPU rounding mode if you want the rounding mode to be “to nearest” the rest of the time, and there probably exist bit-twiddling tricks that can speed up the extraction of the largest odd divisor of `d`.

Comment: `while (d % 2) d /= 2;` has the corner advantage of not relying on 2's complement.

Comment: @chux Last I checked, compilers didn’t replace division by a simple shift when the integer type was signed. Here the division is exact and the transformation valid but an insufficiently smart compiler may generate something more complex for /=2 than for >>=1

Comment: Given two’s complement and non-zero `d`, the largest odd divisor of. `d` is `d / (d & -d)`.

Comment: @Pascal Thank you, this one looks promising. But the while(d & 1.. is a typo, you mean while(d % 1 ==0), right?

Comment: @Geom `d%1` is always zero, so I definitely do not mean that. I don't think there is a typo, but you can use `d%2` if you are not confident that it's the same as `d&1` (it is).

Answer (score 4):

If a hardware FMA is available, then, in most cases (cases where `n` is expected not to be small, per below), the fastest test may be:

```
#include <cmath>
…
double q = dn/dd;
if (std::fma(-q, dd, dn))
    std::cout << "Quotient was not exact.\n";
```

This can fail if *nd*−*q*•*dd* is so small it is rounded to zero, which occurs in round-to-nearest-ties-to-even mode if its magnitude is smaller than half the smallest representable positive value (commonly 2<sup>−1074</sup>). That can happen only if `dn` itself is small. I expect I could calculate some bound on `dn` for that if desired, and, given that `dn` = `n` and `n` is an integer, that should not occur.

Ignoring the exponent bounds, a way to test the significands for divisibility is:

```
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath>
…
int sink; // Needed for frexp argument but will be ignored.
double fn = std::ldexp(std::frexp(n, &sink), DBL_MANT_DIG);
double fd = std::frexp(d, &sink);
if (std::fmod(fn, fd))
    std::cout << "Quotient will not be exact.\n";
```

Given that *n* and *d* are integers that are exactly representable in the floating-point type, I think we could show their exponents cannot be such that the above test would fail. There are cases where *n* is a small integer and *d* is large (a value from 2<sup>1023</sup> to 2<sup>1024</sup>−2<sup>972</sup>, inclusive) that I need to think about.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a reliable way in C++ to check if `double result = dn/dd` contains a rounding error?

Should your system allow access to the various FP flags, test for `FE_INEXACT` after the division.

If FP code is expensive, than at least this code can be used to check integer only solutions.

---

A C solution follow, (I do not have access to a compliant C++ compiler to test right now)

```
#include <fenv.h>
// Return 0: no rounding error
// Return 1: rounding error
// Return -1: uncertain
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
int Rounding_error_detection(int n, int d) {
  double dn = n;
  double dd = d;

  if (feclearexcept(FE_INEXACT)) return -1;
  volatile double result = dn/dd;
  (void) result;
  int set_excepts = fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT);
  return set_excepts != 0;
}
```

Test code

```
void Rounding_error_detection_Test(int n, int d) {
  printf("Rounding_error_detection(%d, %d) --> %d\n", 
    n, d, Rounding_error_detection(n,d));
}

int main(void) {
  Rounding_error_detection_Test(3, 6);
  Rounding_error_detection_Test(3, 7);
}
```

Output

```
Rounding_error_detection(3, 6) --> 0
Rounding_error_detection(3, 7) --> 1
```

Comment: For GCC, it's not enough to have the statement `(void) result;`, unless I am doing something wrong (https://godbolt.org/g/DrahMk , GCC famously does not support `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` but `-frounding-math` is advertised as the file-scope workaround. Using a volatile variable `result` happens to help.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Code amended per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If the quotient `q=dn/dd` is exact, it will divide dn exactly dd times.
Since you have dd being integer, you could test exactness with integer division.
Instead of testing the quotient multiplied by dd with `(dn/dd)*dd==dn` where round off errors can compensate, you should rather test the remainder.
Indeed `std:remainder` is always exact:

```
if(std:remainder(dn,dn/dd)!=0)
    std::cout << "Quotient was not exact." << std::endl;
```